# Why extension always in "Repos" menu?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Create an extension for devops
Here is my manifest file. But no matter how I build. My extension always appears in the "Repos" menu, as if I indicated in the Azure Repos categories. Why is it going this way?

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "7pacePlugin",
    "publisher": "Dmitry",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "name": "TimeTrackingInvoices",
    "description": "A sample Visual Studio Services extension",
        "categories":["Azure Boards"],
    "public": false,

    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "invoices",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-code-web.code-hub-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Invoices",
                "uri": "Invoices.html",
                                "iconAsset": "Dmitry.7pacePlugin/images/icon.png",
                                "_sharedData": {
                                           "assets": [
                                        "Dmitry.7pacePlugin/images/icon.png"
                                             ]
                                        }
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "Invoices.html",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib",
            "addressable": true,
            "packagePath": "lib"
        },
                {
         "path": "images/icon.png",
         "addressable": true
     }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Hi, how about Daniel's solution?  If it could help you solve the issue, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues or facing other puzzle, please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 1):

It's appearing with your repos because you're telling it to appear there:

```
"targets": [
    "ms.vss-code-web.code-hub-group"
]
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=azure-devops) to see what options you have for where your extension appears.